# How do I dynamically update a calculated value based on the number of input values in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, rshiny

I am trying to update the value in a plotly chart in R shiny whose calculated value depends on the number of inputs

```
library(shiny)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(shinythemes)
library(flexdashboard)
library(shinydashboard)

setwd("X:/Work/Covid-19 Project/Shiny Dashboard")

rp_1 <- read.csv("Data/Risk Profile 1.csv")
rp_2 <- read.csv("Data/Risk Profile 2.csv")

gender <- c("Male","Female")
age <- c("Less than 20 years", "20 to 50 years","More than 50 years")
city <- c("Delhi","Chennai")
diabetes <- c("Have diabetes","Don't have diabetes")
hypertension <- c("Have hypertension","Don't have hypertension")

risk_level_est <- function(city, gender, age, db, ht){
  p_inv <- as.numeric(rp_1 %>%
                        filter(City == city & Gender == gender) %>%
                        select(Prob))
  
  p_adv <- as.numeric(rp_2 %>%
                        filter(Age == age & Diabetes == db & Hypertension == ht) %>%
                        summarise(Hosp + Death))
  
  as.numeric(p_inv*p_adv*100)
}

sar_risk_level_est <- function(age, db, ht){
  p_adv <- as.numeric(rp_2 %>%
                        filter(Age == age & Diabetes == db & Hypertension == ht) %>%
                        summarise(Hosp + Death))
  
  as.numeric(0.2*p_adv*100)
}

about_page <- tabPanel(
  title = "About",
  titlePanel("About"),
  "Created with R Shiny",
  br(),
  "2021 April"
)

main_page <- tabPanel(
  title = "Estimator",
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      title = "Inputs",
      selectInput("gender", "Select your gender", gender),
      selectInput("age", "Select your age", age),
      selectInput("city", "Select your city", city),
      selectInput("db", "Do you have diabetes", diabetes),
      selectInput("ht", "Do you have hypertension", hypertension),
      radioButtons("radio", "Do you want to include your household members",
                   choices = list("No" = 1,"Yes" = 2)),
      conditionalPanel("input.radio == 2",
                       numericInput("members", label = "How many household members do you have?", value='1'),
                       uiOutput("member_input")
      ),
      actionButton("risk","Calculate my risk profile")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          title = "Risk Profile",
          plotlyOutput("risk_profile", height = 250, width = "75%"),
          plotlyOutput("overall_risk_profile", height = 250, width = "75%")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Risk Estimator",
  theme = shinytheme('united'),
  main_page,
  about_page
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$member_input <- renderUI({
    
    numMembers <- as.integer(input$members)
    
    lapply(1:numMembers, function(i) {
      list(tags$p(tags$u(h4(paste0("Member ", i)))),
           selectInput(paste0("age", i), "Select their age", age, selected = NULL),
           selectInput(paste0("db", i), "Do they have diabetes", diabetes, selected = NULL),
           selectInput(paste0("ht", i), "Do they have hypertension", hypertension, selected = NULL))
    })
  })
  
  risk_level <- eventReactive(input$risk, {
    risk_level_est(input$city, input$gender, input$age, input$db, input$ht)
  })
  
  sar_risk_level <- eventReactive(input$risk,{
    
    sar_risk <- 0
    
    lapply(1:input$members, function(i){
      sar_risk <- sar_risk + sar_risk_level_est(input[[paste0("age", i)]],input[[paste0("db", i)]],input[[paste0("ht", i)]])
    })
    
    as.numeric(sar_risk)
  })
  
  output$risk_profile <- renderPlotly({
    
    fig <- plot_ly(
      domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
      value = risk_level(),
      title = list(text = "Personal Risk Profile"),
      type = "indicator",
      mode = "gauge+number",
      gauge = list(
        axis = list(range = list(0, 15)),
        bar = list(color = "gray"),
        bgcolor = "white",
        borderwidth = 2,
        bordercolor = "gray",
        steps = list(
          list(range = c(0, 3.75), color = "darkgreen"),
          list(range = c(3.75, 7.5), color = "chartreuse"),
          list(range = c(7.5,11.25), color = "orange"),
          list(range = c(11.25,15), color = "red")
        ))) 
    fig <- fig %>% layout(margin = list(l=30, r=30, t=80, b=30))
    
    fig
  })
  
  output$overall_risk_profile <- renderPlotly({
    
    fig <- plot_ly(
      domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
      value = risk_level() + sar_risk_level(),
      title = list(text = "Overall Risk Profile"),
      type = "indicator",
      mode = "gauge+number",
      gauge = list(
        axis = list(range = list(0, 15+(25*input*members))),
        bar = list(color = "gray"),
        bgcolor = "white",
        borderwidth = 2,
        bordercolor = "gray",
        steps = list(
          list(range = c(0, 3.75), color = "darkgreen"),
          list(range = c(3.75, 7.5), color = "chartreuse"),
          list(range = c(7.5,11.25), color = "orange"),
          list(range = c(11.25,15), color = "red")
        ))) 
    fig <- fig %>% layout(margin = list(l=30, r=30, t=80, b=30))
    
    fig
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

While the risk_profile plot works fine, the overall_risk_profile plot throws the "*non-numeric argument to binary operator*" error. The sar_risk_level() value in overall_risk_profile  is dependent on a calculation  (sar_risk_level_est) which depends on the number of inputs. I want this value (sar_risk) to be initizialied to zero and updated everytime the action button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Great looking app. I think it is just a typo. The code has `25*input*members` instead of `25*input$members` on line 151.

Comment: Thanks! And yeah it was the typo that caused the error, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Sometimes we all need a second pair of eyes :)